# Как посмотреть почему вылетает exe файл

Tags: python

Собрал проект(это графический интерфейс на kivy\kivymd) в exe файл при помощи auto-py-to-exe, но при запуске exe сразу же вылетает, как узнать причину вылета, как посмотреть log

Comment: Запустить через терминал?

Comment: @andreymal нет, просто запускается файл лога нет